# Layout bug on bounties tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

If there are no elements on the list the tabs falls to the left...

[image: bounties bug]

I am using Firefox 4, Windows 7.

Comment: I can repro with FF4 on XP, I do *not* see it with Chrome (latest) on XP or IE8 on XP

Comment: @Daniel ~ Firefox4? That is sooooo three months ago!

Comment: @jcolebrand okay fine smartypants I repro with FF5 on the same cutting edge OS I mentioned above!

Comment: @daniel ~ LMAO!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build, an unnecessary `float: left;` for that class elsewhere was interfering here.